# How to detect real time onsets?

Tags: sound, realtime

Hey Ladies and Gentlemen, I'm a Software Engineer Undergraduate. I'm trying to detect drum strokes(beats) in real-time in python. I used amplitude threshold-based onset detect (beat detect) algorithm but it takes other noises also onsets and it omits some actual beats with low amplitude. Can you have suggestions to optimize my code or another way to solve this?

Comment: This probably belongs on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ . It's beyond the remit of sound designers.

Comment: Thank You very much @Tetsujin

Comment: You probably need to investigate a cross-correlation method and rather than using sample level, look at using RMS integration across a short buffer length to determine beat location and level.